# Как получить путь до Desktop пользователя внутри сервиса

Tags: c#, winapi

Пишу сервис для создания ярлыка при логине пользователя.
Есть ли способ получения пути до Desktop для указанного пользователя?
Можно конечно запускать сервис из под пользователя, и получить для него путь.
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)

А потом подменить пользователя на нужного в пути, но что делать, если сервис из под системы запущен?!

Comment: Если сервис расчитан на работе с данными текущего пользователя, то зачем его от имени системы запускать? А так, посмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5218778/12888024).

Comment: Сервис работает с любым пользователем входящим в систему. Создает ярлык при логине. Но запущен он может быть как из под пользователя так и под системой. Если сервис запущен под системой, то Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) ничего не вернет